# SCSS to CSS - how to fix media queries

Tags: css, sass

used 'scss to css' converter but have problems about media queries.

I was using 'codepen.io' site to use templates on my practice page. The css part was made with scss and I converted to css with 'scss to css' online converter. I have no idea to fix the problem of media queries inside h1 css class. how can I fix this in css?

```
h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 15px 0;

        @media (min-width: 400px) {
            font-size: 4.5em;
        }

        @media (min-width: 440px) {
            font-size: 5.5em;
        }

        @media (min-width: 500px) {
            font-size: 6.5em;
        }

        @media (min-width: 630px) {
            font-size: 7.5em;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            font-size: 9em;
            padding-bottom: 15px * 2;
        }

        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
            font-size: 12em;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What issue are you having? That's perfectly valid Sass.

Answer (score 2):

you need to write valid css media query

```
h1 {
        font-size: 4em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 15px 0;

   }

@media (min-width: 400px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 4.5em;
           }
   }

@media (min-width: 440px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 5.5em;
           }
   }

// ...keep going like this
```

Comment: SCSS allows it to be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

in the css you can not set style for media in one tag styling.
for example for h1:

```
h1{
 font-size: 4em;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}
h2{
color: red;
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 12em;
      }
h2{
color: blue;
}
    }
```

Comment: This is Sass, not vanilla CSS. The example provided is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your css with https://www.sassmeister.com/ and all works as expected, the generated css is valid.

```
   h1 {
      font-size: 4em;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 0 15px 0;
    }
    @media (min-width: 400px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 4.5em;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 440px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 5.5em;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 500px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 6.5em;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 630px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 7.5em;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 9em;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 12em;
      }
    }
```

If you want to work with sass (.scss) you can convert your source to .css also from command line using cli like dart:
https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass

Or if you want there are a lot of other software the do a real time conversion in a lot of programming language.